# Magento2 add extra fee in Muti Shipping Checkout

Tags: magento2, multishipping

i want to add extra fee in multi shipping based on the item
if item is one than add $5
and
if 2 item than add $10

how can i do that ??

my collect function is like below

```
public function collect(
    Quote $quote,
    ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
    Total $total
)
{

    parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);

    if (!sizeof($shippingAssignment->getItems())) {
        return $this;
    }

    $quote->setFee(0);
    $total->setTotalAmount('fee', 0);
    $total->setBaseTotalAmount('fee', 0);

        $getShippingAddresses = $quote->getAllShippingAddresses();
        foreach ($getShippingAddresses as $address) {
            $fee = 20;

            $totals = $address->getTotals();
            $address->setTotalAmount('fee', $fee);
            $address->setTotalAmount('fee', $fee);
        }

    return $this;
}
```

its not work, not add fee

Comment: Why are you not using extra fee extension instead ?

Comment: is that extra fee extension work with multi shipping checkout?

Comment: Don't know but use this extension and tell me if its works. magecomp.com/magento-2-extra-fee.html

Comment: not working with multi shipping checkout

Comment: In your question, you'r writing above code in Tax.php ?

Comment: no in my cusotm extenison file

Comment: Yes Yes, but what's your file name ?